# Can I define eager loading per datacontext instead per query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datacontext, eager-loading

Is there a way to define eager loading per entire data context, so I could state something like this -- "when using this data context when loading Customer always load associated City as well"?

So, something very similar to Options and LoadWith in Linq to Sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Entity framework doesn't offer equivalent to `DataLoadOptions` available in Linq-to-Sql. There is no way to define something like `LoadWith` or `AssociateWith` globally.

Comment: Why not do this in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Like Ladislav said, there currently is no way to do this in EF.  However, the question comes back to why you want to do this globally rather than on a per-query basis.

If your main purpose is to abstract away eager loading out of your business layer, one options is to do something like I describe on in a blog post I wrote [here](http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/allowing-eager-loading-in-business-logic-via-view-models/). Essentially it describes a library that I want to create (time permitting) where it automatically determines how to eager load by looking at the data structure a query should be based around.

However, I don't know if that would solve the core issue of what you are trying to do or not without more detail of why you want this globally

Comment: I did something very similar in my last project. I had some collection of predefined eager loadings in unit of work which could be controlled by consumer and when repository returned default query it included all reasonable eager loading options but it worked only for single level of eager loading.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, to have them defined in the unit of work.  I wonder how hard it would be for you to combine them together to achieve multiple levels, though that may add too many methods to the unit of work interface.

Comment: In my case I would like to set all the loadings in datacontext because (1) it is migration from L2S ;-) (2) the logic of DB (3) logic of operations performed on the data. It makes more sense to set it once for good in one place (creation of DC) then later setting this in code per query.

Comment: Ah.  Unfortunately, eager loading is one area that makes ORM migrations non-seamles.  However, I would argue that it's more efficient (sql-wise at least) to set eager loading per query, as what you need to eager load is heavily dependent on how you are going to use each individual query, and globally setting eager loading can result in much more data being returned than needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the data load options in the constructor of your DataContext:

```
public MyDataContext() : 
  base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
{
    DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
    options.LoadWith<Customer>(o => o.City);
    this.LoadOptions = options;
    OnCreated();
}
```

This will eager load the attribute every time.